# I set my AWS keys and they show up in linux terminal, but Rails 4 app can't find them. Using aws-sdk and carrierwave-aws gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, env

Here's my carrierwave config file:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.storage    = :aws
  config.aws_bucket = ENV.fetch('S3_BUCKET_NAME')
  config.aws_acl    = :public_read
  config.asset_host = 'http://example.com'

config.aws_credentials = {
  access_key_id:     ENV.fetch('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
  secret_access_key: ENV.fetch('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
```

}

end

The server won't start and returns:

14:53:23 web.1  | /home/tom/paul/config/initializers/carrierwave.rb:9:in `fetch': key not found: "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID" (KeyError)

I entered the keys like this in the command line:

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="demo12345"
```

both with and without the quote marks

the command

```
env
```

displays them OK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be changed/edit in config/environments/development.rb
as it:

```
S3_BUCKET_NAME=    ******your bucket name ****
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID= ******your acess key_id***
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY= ********* your secret key ***
AWS_REGION=            ******* your region ***
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use the Gem 'Figaro' to help manage environment variables. Very easy to set-up and manage.

1) Add to your Gemfile and bundle:

```
gem 'figaro', '1.0'
```

2) run 'figaro install'

```
figaro install
```

3) Open up the generated file: config/application.yml and add the variables:

```
SAMPLE_PASSWORD: exAmplePa$$
SAMPLE_USERNAME: myspecialusername
```

4) Go back into your initializer file and change your variable too:

```
user_name:      ENV['SAMPLE_USERNAME'],
password:       ENV['SAMPLE_PASSWORD'],
```

You should be good to go!